# Swift CallKit Identiftying

Tags: swift, swift3, callkit

I'm trying to use CallKit in Swift to identify a caller.
I'm searching for a way to identify the caller by making an URL request. 
For example: +1-234-45-241 calls me, I want it to make a request to 
mydomain.com/phone?number=+1-234-45-241 but how can I do this? I can't find a way for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the incoming call number by using callkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098036/how-to-get-the-incoming-call-number-by-using-callkit)

Answer (score 1):

What you describe isn't possible. CallKit works differently to your scenario.

The phone app requests a CallKit extension to provide a collection of phone numbers which it knows about, together with a descriptor for each. The phone app doesn't disclose the calling number. If the collection of phone numbers provided by the extension contains the calling number, then the phone app will display the descriptor.

More information in the [Apple CallKit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit?language=objc) reference.

And, specifically, note this advisory note in the reference:

> Because this method is called only when the system launches the app extension and not for each individual call, you must specify call identification information all at once; you cannot, for example, make a request to a web service to find information about an incoming call.