# Get caller number from app when it is in background or in open state in iOS 10 or below?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios10, callkit

I am looking for some source code for iOS 10 and below by which I can get the caller number when some phone call arrived and that call can be rejected by the application, if call is some fraud call (checking the local database).

I have followed following post but did not get any fruitful result.

Via call kit: [how to get the incoming call number by using callkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098036/how-to-get-the-incoming-call-number-by-using-callkit)

True caller app already added that feature: https://blog.truecaller.com/2016/10/26/truecaller-now-available-on-ios-10/

I think it is possible, can anyone help me by giving some idea or source code by which that can be achieved?

Comment: True caller doesnt reject calls. It shows a UI to identify if call is spam or not! Still user is the one who decides whether to reject the call or not!

Comment: Yes you are right @TejaNandamuri , Atleast they are getting the number where from the call arrived, is that possible on or below iOS 10?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to get caller's number when user receives a call. Truecaller has a lot of conditions for it to be able to show caller's details. The truecaller app should be active. The caller should call using the truecaller app. Both the calling and call receiving devices should be connected to the internet.

So what it basically does is that when a user presses the call button on the app to call somebody, they simply send him a notification that this person is calling you. It has nothing to do with CallKit and the caller id is not displayed on the call receiving screen.